# Selection indicator not showing in picker view inside an action sheet

Tags: ios, ios5, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

Here's my implementation, I'm basically creating the action sheet and picker view on the fly.  The problem is the indicator to show which item you have selected isn't showing.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault; 

UIPickerView* picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100, 320, 216)]; 
picker.dataSource = self; 
picker.delegate = self; 

[actionSheet addSubview:picker]; 


[actionSheet showInView:self.view]; 

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 411)];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're missing this line:

```
[picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
```

Comment: That was it, I knew it was something simple I was missing.